# How to convert javascript snipped to coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
//Trying to convert zis javascript...
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

//To zis coffee-script
http.createServer(app).listen app.get('port'), (x) ->
  console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get 'port'
```

My question is: Do I have to use parenthesis when I supply app.get('port')'s value as the first argument to "listen"
If I write the snippet without using parenthesis:

```
http.createServer(app).listen app.get'port' (x) ->
      console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get 'port'
```

Wont the callback function be passed as the second argument to app.get?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Just because you often *can* call functions without parentheses, that doesn't mean you *should*. When chaining function calls like this, you should use parentheses for clarity even when the precedence is what you want.

Comment: why dont you just look at the generated javascript ? you'll have your answer.

Comment: Also, your CS is not equivalent to your JS, because you use `(x) ->` in the former but `function ()` in the latter.  You want either just `->` in the CS or `function (x)` in the JS.

Comment: you can write the snippet without parentheses, but not without the comma after app.get 'port'

Answer (score 2):

In short, the conversion looks like this:

```
http.createServer(app).listen app.get('port'), ->
    console.log "Express server listening on port #{app.get 'port'}"
```

---

A bit more explanation:

CoffeeScript's parenthesis are optional unless the function takes no arguments. So if you're calling a function that takes two arguments, the following two are equivalent:

```
Math.max(5, 12)
Math.max 5, 12
```

Like `Math.max`, `http.createServer(app).listen` seems to take two arguments: a port (it seems) and a callback function.

You could just as easily write it like this, which might be a bit more clear.

```
serverListeningCallback = ->
    console.log "Express server listening on port #{app.get 'port'}"

http.createServer(app).listen app.get('port'), serverListeningCallback
```

I'd recommend the solution at the top, but the above might make the solution more clear.

---

PS: Note [CoffeeScript's string interpolation](http://coffeescript.org/#strings). The following are equivalent in CoffeeScript:

```
"My favorite number is " + Math.random()
"My favorite number is #{Math.random}"
```